# Trying to understand what an expression tree is

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, expression-trees

Both snippets below product the same output.
I understand how Func encapsulates a method with a single parameter, and returns a bool value.  And you can either assign it a
method, anonymous method or a lambda expression.

```
Func<int, bool> deleg = i => i < 5;
Console.WriteLine("deleg(4) = {0}", deleg(4));
```

Below is using expression trees which I don't fully understand yet.  Why would I want to do it this way? Is it more flexible, what advantage does it give me?

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<int, bool>> expr = i => i < 5;
Func<int, bool> deleg2 = expr.Compile();
Console.WriteLine("deleg2(4) = {0}", deleg2(4));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the Expression tree is the body of a lambda expression, that allows you to

- introspect the expression (see *what's in it* so to say)
- manipulate the expression (simplify, extend (e.g. add new functionality or modify to work on different items).

Once you `Compile()` the expression, it is *just another delegate*, which you can only *call*, not inspect or modify.

Whenever you want to

- create expressions dynamically (I mean: construct, not allocate)
- operate on expressions dynamically

the `Function<>` types are not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The point of expression trees is that you can do more with them than just compile them to a function. You can inspect them, modify them and compile them to something other than .net functions.

For example Linq2SQL compiles expression trees to SQL code. You couldn't do that with a plain .net function.

Comment: how do you inspect them? what is that process called? examples?

Comment: @codecompleting: Using the methods and properties of the [Expression class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx) and its [subclasses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx#inheritanceContinued). You can see a small example in [this article](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/working-with-expression-trees-part-1/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example you just have "hardcoded" the body of the function and assigned it to a delegate.

In your second example the assignment constructs an expression-tree which is an object model reprensenting your code in a data structure in memory.

The advantage is that you can modify and inspect that datastructure.

LINQ2SQL for example uses that technique to translate your expressions to another language called SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Expression trees are regular in-memory data structures that can be traversed programmatically and the result of such traversal can be something, like a query you'd like to send to the database. Read more on the `ExpressionVisitor` class to see how it is done.

On the other hand, the compiled function is nothing more than a sequence of CIL code. You still can inspect it programmatically but you are not inspecting the definition but rather - the compiler output of it.